# upgrade code rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn to fit with tensorflow 2.0 API

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.contrib import rnn
lstm_f = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
lstm_b = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
blstm_out, state_f, state_b = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_f, lstm_b, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The code above works with tensorflow 1.x, however I feel hard to find a way to rewrite this code using tensorflow 2.0 API.

I know I should start with tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(), but I don't know what is the API function to fit with 2 LSTMCell instances as the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Keras equivalent of your snippet would be

```
lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(n_hidden, unit_forget_bias=True, unroll=True)
keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm)
```

Note that while Keras has an implementation of `LSTMCell`, you might want to use [`LSTM`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) instead, which is not just a cell but a fully unrolled RNN operating on the whole sequence at once. By default, the RNN is unrolled dynamically via a while loop, we force it to be static (in TF 1.X terms) by passing `unroll=True`. Finally, [`keras.layers.Bidirectional`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#bidirectional) wrapper makes an RNN bidirectional.